# Напишите функцию, которая считает количество гласных в переданной строке

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста. Есть задание чтобы был подсчет гласных. Я не могу понять куда мне писать слово, которое будет считать функция. Если просто в конце вывести функцию и написать слово, то ошибка.
Вот задачка:

> Напишите функцию, которая считает количество гласных в переданной строке.
>
> Программа должна спросить у пользователя в консоли слово и вывести количество гласных в нем.
>
> Пример:
> ведите слово:
>
> длинношеее
>
> Гласных: 5

мой код:

```
def count_v2(word):
    vowels = 0
    consonants = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter.lower() in 'aeiouyауоыиэяюёе':
                vowels += 1
            else:
                consonants += 1
 
    return (vowels, consonants)
```

Comment: куда писать слово написано в главе учебника про функции.

Comment: Если вы отправляете ваш код в какую-то тестирующую систему, то это нужно в самой системе искать описание того, в каком формате нужно принимать и выводить данные. Часто данные принимаются через input(), а выводятся просто через print(). Но могут быть и другие варианты. Так что нужно искать в документации к проверяющей системе конкретные указания на этот счёт.

Comment: кстати если загуглить этот вопрос и дописать в конце python по 1 ссылке будет код 1 в 1. Без ввода и вывода. Просто 1 функция

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так устраивает?

```
# запросить текст у пользователя
text = input("введите текст: ").lower()

# подсчитать кол-во гласным
count = 0

for vowel in 'аеиоуюя':
    count += text.count(vowel)

# вывести результат:
print(count)
```

можно и в 1 строку, но это небольшой изврат:

```
# подсчитать кол-во гласным
count = len(list(filter(lambda letter: letter in 'аеиоуюя', text)))
```

Comment: можно так:`print(sum(map(text.count, 'аеиоуюя')))`

Comment: да, еще круче - что-то не подумал :)

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь!